# warning sending mail via localhost

Tags: php, smtp, wampserver

i had an issue with sending email from localhost server

I've got this problem :

**mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\mail.php on line 14**

Line 14 :

```
 mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
```

i configured sendmail.ini :

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

smtp_port=465

smtp_ssl=ssl

default_domain=localhost

error_logfile=error.log

;debug_logfile=debug.log

auth_username= haythem.belhadj@esprit.tn

auth_password=******

pop3_server=

pop3_username=

pop3_password=

force_sender= haythem.belhadj@esprit.tn

force_recipient=

hostname=localhost
```

also php.ini files in apache and php folders added this line

**"C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"**

what should i do ?

Comment: Refer this link http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-using-wamp-server/

Comment: i dont find php_smtp extension

Comment: Open PHP.ini search for smtp, you will find something like smtp_port check it value, use same in your code

Comment: i downloaded php_smtp.dll and added extension=php_smtp.dll in php.ini but i dont find it when i click wamp->php->php_extensions

Answer (score 0):

Open php.ini file and uncomment **php_openssl, php_smtp and php_sockets** and restart all services.

Comment: i downloaded php_smtp.dll and added extension=php_smtp.dll in php.ini but i dont find it when i click wamp->php->php_extensions